# Fast way to check if a list of points is close to a list of linestrings in python with shapely and geopandas

Tags: python, geometry, gis, geopandas, shapely

I have a large list of shapely points (around 150k) and a large list of shapely linestrings (around 240k). I was wondering if there was a fast way to check if these points are close to any of the linestrings.

This was the code I used for 300 points and it took 387 seconds.

```py
on_road = []

for point in noisePoints.geometry:
    if (roads_df.geometry.distance(point) < 1e-4).any():
        on_road.append(point)
```

This method is way too slow so I am hoping for a faster method.

Comment: Could you possibly share som data to test an alternative method? But, I believe this is a pretty neat solution actually. One alternative if bufferring the linestrings and then doing a sjoin. But I suspect it would be slower. But do share.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dask-Geopandas](https://github.com/geopandas/dask-geopandas) it can partition your Geopandas dataframe and run any such shapely operations in parallel. Try creating your 'roads_df' as a Dask Geopandas dataframe and try running the same code. It should look something like this

```
roads_ddf = dask_geopandas.from_geopandas(roads_df, npartitions=4)
on_road = []
for point in noisePoints.geometry:
    if (roads_ddf.geometry.distance(point) < 1e-4).any():
        on_road.append(point)
```

Answer (score 0):

- an approach that works well is https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html
- using UK motorway network for *LineString* and NHS hospitals for *Point* geometry.  This gives 227 hospitals and 3669 road segments

```
153 ms ± 3.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

- have used CRS of data from Ordinance Survey. It does work with epsg:4326, however you will get warnings when you do spatial join

#### solution

```
# find nearest line to each point (hospital)
def nr_dist():
    gdfn = gpd.sjoin_nearest(
        gdfh.to_crs(gdf.crs),
        gdf
    ).merge(gdf["geometry"], left_on="index_right", right_index=True, suffixes=("","_line"))
    # calc the distance between the point and linestring
    gdfn["distance"] = gdfn.apply(lambda r: r["geometry_line"].distance(r["geometry"]), axis=1)
    return gdfn

# %timeit gdfn = nr_dist()
gdfn = nr_dist()
```

#### data sourcing

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import numpy as np
import requests, io
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd

# get uk motorway geometry
url = "https://api.os.uk/downloads/v1/products/OpenRoads/downloads?area=GB&format=ESRI®+Shapefile&redirect"
f = Path.cwd().joinpath("road_gp.zip")

if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    zfile.extractall(f.stem)

nf = Path.cwd().joinpath("a-roads")
if not nf.exists():
    nf.mkdir()
nf = nf.joinpath("a-roads.shp")
if nf.exists():
    print("exists")
    gdf = gpd.read_file(nf)
else:
    gdf = pd.concat(
        [
            gpd.read_file(sf)
            .loc[lambda d: d["class"].isin(["Motorway"])]
            .assign(source=sf.stem)
            for sf in list(Path.cwd().joinpath(f.stem).glob("**/*Link.shp"))
        ]
    )

    gdf.to_file(nf)
    
gdf = gdf.loc[~gdf["formOfWay"].isin(["Slip Road", "Roundabout"]),  ["roadNumber", "class", "source", "geometry"]]

# get hospitals and turn into geodataframe
dfhos = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("https://assets.nhs.uk/data/foi/Hospital.csv").text),sep="Č",engine="python",)
dfhos = dfhos.loc[lambda d: d["Sector"].eq("NHS Sector") & d["SubType"].eq("Hospital")].groupby("ParentODSCode", as_index=False).first()

# points for hospitals
gdfh = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=dfhos.loc[:, ["Longitude", "Latitude"]].apply(
        shapely.geometry.Point, axis=1
    ), data=dfhos
).set_crs("epsg:4326").loc[:, ["Sector", "OrganisationName", "County", "geometry"]]
```

#### visualisation

```
# visualise it...
mask = gdf.index.isin(gdfn["index_right"])
m = gdf.loc[mask].explore(color="blue", style_kwds={"weight":6})
m = gdf.loc[~mask].explore(m=m, color="skyblue", style_kwds={"weight":4})
m = gdfn.explore(m=m, color="red")
m
```

[image]